# Masking out the upper or lower 4 bits results in the same image

Tags: image, image-processing

I am processing a 12-bit image which is unfortunately store as a 16-bit tiff. However, I do not know which 4 of the 16 bits are useless. So I tried three methods: mask each pixel with 0xFFF0, 0x0FFF, or 0x0FF0. It appears to me the resulting image of these three methods look just the same, but their md5 values are different. Why does this happen? Are there any differences if I use any of these three images for other purposes later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer monitors can only display 256 distinct brightness levels. A 12-bit image consequently has its lower 4 bits ignored. So you see no difference when you zero out those bits or not.

When a 12-bit image is stored in a 16-bit integer, the upper 4 bits are usually left at zero, so there is no difference when you zero them or not. [Sometimes the pixel value is scaled to occupy the full 16 bit range, but this is not usually the case.]

So, don’t mask out any bits is my recommendation. Zeroing our the lower 4 bits just reduced the precision of the values in the image, making it equivalent to an 8-bit image. Masking the upper 4 bits is pointless because they already are zero.